# How to get grid-view view Label value in java-script or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVPurchaseRequest">

  <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"  HeaderText="Select">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblCheckStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CheckStatus")%>' style="display:none"></asp:Label>
      <asp:Label ID="lblLevelAdded" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LevelAdded")%>' style="display:none"></asp:Label>
      <asp:Label ID="lblAdded_UserID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Added_UserID")%>' style="display:none"></asp:Label>
      <asp:Label ID="lblEjectLevel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LevelEjected")%>' style="display:none"></asp:Label>
      <asp:Label ID="lblCheckReturnStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CheckReturnStatus")%>' style="display:none"></asp:Label>
      <asp:Label ID="lbl_status" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("status")%>'></asp:Label> 
      <asp:CheckBox ID="chkPRID" runat="server" Checked="true" OnClientclick="javascript: return test();"  />      
      <asp:Label ID="lblConPo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Con_To_PO")%>' style="display:none"></asp:Label>                                                                     
      <asp:Label ID="lblConPoF" runat="server" Text="0" style="display:none"></asp:Label>
      <asp:Label ID="lblPR_ID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PR_ID")%>' style="display:none"></asp:Label>
      <asp:Label ID="lblrowIDnd" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID") %>' Style="display:none"></asp:Label>
      <asp:Label ID="lblPR_IDF" runat="server" Text="0" style="display:none"></asp:Label>                                                                                                                                                         <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelGV" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Bind("ID") %>' ToolTip="Delete" AlternateText="Delete" CommandName="Delete" ImageUrl="~/Images/Delete_24x24.png" OnClientClick="javascript:return deletePartNo();"></asp:ImageButton>                                                                        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataGrid>
```

**QUESTION**

How to get `lbl_status` label value in **jquery** or **JavaScript**?...

Comment: is lbl_status the `class` or `id` name?

Comment: lbl_status is label id

Comment: i am trying with this code                                                                          var grid = $('[id$="GVPurchaseRequest"]').find('input:text[id$="lblstatus"]').val() but i could not get value..

Answer (score 0):

You can add a button to get the value?

I haven't test this, but you can give it a go.

```
//LinkButton
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnk" Text="Click Here" runat="server" OnClientClick="getLabelValue(this);" />

 //function
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getLabelValue(element)
    {
        var label = $(element).closest('label').find('label[id*="lbl_status"]').text();
        console.log(label);
    }
</script>
```

or you can try doing this:

```
var label = $("#GVPurchaseRequest").closest('label').find('label[id*="lbl_status"]').text();
        console.log(label);
```

Comment: @Ethirajram Try adding a button to get the value?

Comment: this validation in button event only